# How can i get the Ethernet interface name of the HCA by PCI device of ConnectX-5 device of Mellanox

Tags: linux

How can i get the Ethernet interface name of the HCA by PCI device of ConnectX-5 device of Mellanox.

If i have only full PCI device using the output of lspci -D |grep -i mellanox

Comment: Welcome. You should better ask on [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com) or [Super User](https://superuser.com). This question is [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the sysfs by run the following commands:

ls -la /sys/class/net/ |grep ""

For Example:

ls -la /sys/class/net/ |grep -i 0000:d8:00.0

output:

```
ls -la /sys/class/net/ |grep -i 0000:d8:00.0

lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root 0 May  1 14:21 ens7f0 -> ../../devices/pci0000:d7/0000:d7:00.0/0000:d8:00.0/net/ens7f0
```

OR:

ls /sys/bus/pci/devices//net

For Example:

ls /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:d8:00.0/net

output:

```
ls /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:d8:00.0/net

ens7f0
```